# ¿Cómo hago para llenar 2 jComboBox con conexión a SQL Server?

Tags: java, sql

¿Cómo haría para llenar un segundo *jComboBox* a partir de la llave primaria de un ítem del primer *jComboBox*? En java con conexión a base de datos (SQL SERVER). En este caso tengo una base de datos con las tablas Departamento y Provincia. Estas son las tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_Departamento](
    [idDepartamento] [char](5) NOT NULL,
    [departamento] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
    [idDepartamento] ASC
     )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
  GO
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_Provincia](
   [idProvincia] [char](5) NOT NULL,
   [provincia] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
   [idDepartamento] [char](5) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
   [idProvincia] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
```

Luego tengo los métodos para llenarlos, pero el segundo *jComboBox* se llena con el índice del primero y no con la llave primaria.

```
private void llenarComboDepartamento(){
    try {
        DefaultComboBoxModel x = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        cboDepartamento.setModel(x);
        ArrayList<entDepartamento> lista = datDepartamento.ListaDepartamentos();
        for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){
            x.addElement(lista.get(i));
        }                   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Listando", 
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }   
}

private void llenarComboProvincia(){
    try {
        DefaultComboBoxModel x = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        cboProvincia.setModel(x);
        ArrayList<entProvincia> lista = datProvincia.ListaProvincia(cboDepartamento.getSelectedIndex()+1);
        for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){
            x.addElement(lista.get(i));
        }           
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Listando", 
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }   

}
```

Espero que me haya hecho entender, soy nuevo en esta comunidad. Agradecería que me apoyaran.

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes ponerle un listener a tu JCombo

combo.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        cargaOtroJCombo();
    }
});

Espero te sirva
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void llenarComboProvincia(){
try {
    DefaultComboBoxModel x = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    // aun no deberias setear el model con cboProvincia.setModel(x);
    ArrayList<entProvincia> lista = datProvincia.ListaProvincia(cboDepartamento.getSelectedIndex()+1);
    for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){
        x.addElement(lista.get(i));
    } 
    //cuando todo el modelo esta lleno ahi si seteas el modelo
    cboProvincia.setModel(x)

} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Listando", 
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

}

creo que tambien debes modificar el otro metodo